# Visualizing top occur words from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a pandas series and want to plot the most frequent words.

my series is already tokenized and removed stop words.

`series` :

```
0        [laptop, sit, 4, star, similarly, price, compa...
1        [order, monitor, want, makeshift, area, powerf...
2        [monitor, great, deal, price, size, ., use, of...
3        [buy, height, adjustment, ., swivel, ability, ...
4        [work, month, die, ., 5, call, hp, support, nu...
                               ...                        
30618                                        [great, deal]
30619                                  [pour, le, travail]
30620                                      [business, use]
30621                                         [good, size]
30622    [pour, mon, ordinateur.plus, grande, image.vra...
Name: text_body, Length: 30623, dtype: object
```

I want to use seaborn to plot graph representing top words.

```
counter=Counter(str(series))
most=counter.most_common()
x=[]
y=[]
for word,count in most[:20]:
        x.append(word)
        y.append(count)

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,10)})
sns.barplot(x=y,y=x)
```

[image: Top frequent word]

the graph only shows top characters instead of words. what did I did wrong?

Comment: `str(series)` turns it into a string for example `str(Series([1, 2, 3]))` -> `'0    1\n1    2\n2    3\ndtype: int64'`

Comment: Instead you can `.explode` and do `.value_counts`